# Python matplotlib different color for each level

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, colors

I want to make different colors for each level and not all of the graph's levels to be blue. How can I do that? I did not find any answer for my specific problem with my specific graph type.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(["None", "2 kg", "3kg"])
y = np.array([10.7, 8.0, 6.0])

plt.title("Car Weight")

plt.xlabel("Weight(Kg)")
plt.ylabel("Distance(Km)")

plt.bar(x, y, color="#0066ff", width=0.2)
plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: You can just give a list of colors: `plt.bar(..., color=['red', 'green', 'blue'])` as mentioned in the [official barplot doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add differents bars and select one color for each one:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(["None", "2 kg", "3kg"])
y = np.array([10.7, 8.0, 6.0])

plt.title("Car Weight")

plt.xlabel("Weight(Kg)")
plt.ylabel("Distance(Km)")

plt.bar(x[0], y[0], color="#0066ff", width=0.2)
plt.bar(x[1], y[1], color="#ff66f7", width=0.2)
plt.bar(x[2], y[2], color="#000000", width=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]